# Problem with auto-build using DevTools springboot plugin on intellij CE versione 2023.2

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-boot-devtools

I'm developing a spring-boot project in Intellij Idea versione 2023.2 and I'm using DevTools dependency. I just modified the IDE in order to use properly DevTools dependency.
I changed Intellij IDEA Settings in this way:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAWTm.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJF4G.png)

But DevTools doesn't work and in the IDE shows the following error in auto-build window:

"Error:Maven resources compiler: Maven project configuration required for module 'my-project' isn't available. Compilation of Maven projects is supported only if external build is started from an IDE."

Have someone an idea to solve this issue?
thank you

Comment: Ensure that your project was recognized by the IDE as a Maven one. Try to right-click on pom.xml and select "Add as Maven Project" if you have this option listed

Comment: I solve it. Problem was intellij, I have modified other settings and I have solved it. Thank for your answer.